# What causes drag crisis?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, drag, aerodynamics, viscosity, turbulence

While reading the [Wikipedia article on Drag Crisis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_crisis), I found:

> The drag crisis is associated with a transition from laminar to
> turbulent boundary layer flow adjacent to the object.

While, the [Wikipedia article on Turbulence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turbulence) states:

> In general terms, in turbulent flow, unsteady vortices of many sizes appear
> which interact with each other; consequently, drag due to
> friction effects increases.

If drag (due to friction effects) increases due to turbulence, then why does drag crisis occur when flow shifts from laminar to turbulent? **Shouldn't drag be less for laminar as compared to turbulent flow**? Why else would surfaces smoothen due to drag over time?

The [Wikipedia article on Drag Crisis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Drag_crisis) also goes on to say:

> For cylindrical structures, this transition is associated with a
> transition from well-organized vortex shedding to randomized shedding
> behavior for super-critical Reynolds numbers, eventually returning to
> well-organized shedding at a higher Reynolds number with a return to
> elevated drag force coefficients.

I am having trouble understanding this.

---

A related question, [Drag Crisis and Terminal Velocity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/628407/), examines the relationship between drag coefficient and terminal velocity.

Comment: Why would anybody consider this a crisis?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, the frictional drag associated with a turbulent boundary layer is greater than that of a laminar boundary layer.

But, for a non-profiled object, most of the drag is form drag: the boundary layer separate and the pressure in the wake is much lower than the pressure in front of the object.

In the case of a turbulent boundary layer, the separation of the boundary layer is delayed by more efficient exchanges with the main flow. As a result, the wake behind the object is narrower and the area where the flow looks like a perfect flow is larger.

By exaggerating a little, we can say that we are approaching the situation described by d'Alembert's paradox : no drag for a perfect flow.

Hope it can help and sorry for my poor english.

Answer (score 0):

Your given link explains this.

> The drag crisis is associated with a transition from laminar to
> turbulent boundary layer flow adjacent to the object. For cylindrical
> structures, this transition is associated with a transition from
> well-organized vortex shedding to randomized shedding behavior for
> super-critical Reynolds numbers, **eventually returning to
> well-organized shedding at a higher Reynolds number with a return to
> elevated drag force coefficients**.

I understand it like this. [Vortex shedding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vortex_shedding) frequency depends on Reynolds number, like this :

$$ f_{shedding}(\text{Re}) = \frac {\text{St} \cdot \text{Re} \cdot \nu}{L^2} \tag 1$$

Where $\text{St}$ is [Strouhal number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strouhal_number), $\nu$ - kinematic viscosity, and $L$ characteristic linear dimension.

For very high vortex shedding frequencies (high $Re$ numbers), flow approaches laminar behavior.

It's like imagine you are going with jeep in a "bumpy" off-road at low speeds, so you feel every pit and clod in the road, but when your driving speed increases sharply, then you feel less jittering in amplitude.